# SQL power Archit

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi have a quick question I've been on this question for some time now and I don't know this answer to this question.

"which of the following database types requires you to avoid the three anomalies"

```
A. Management Information Systems
B. Knowledge Management Systems
C. Warehouse
D. Transaction Processing System
```

You are creating a small database for a jewelry store. You schedule a meeting with the owner to discuss the project and get an idea of what the database will require. The owner mentions how he would like the database to be shared on his network in the shop, produce numerous reports, include security and be visible on his website. Before you begin drafting your first model, you take a look at your schedule and realize that you may not have time to add the security and the web site visibility. What do you need to construct for the owner so that he knows what you are able to do and not to do with regards to this project?

```
A. Security Requirements
B. Problem Statement
C. Objectives
D. Scope
```

You are designing a database for a jewelry store and need to create an entity called ORDER. Within this entity you need an attribute called OrderDate and ShipDate. When the user enters the ShipDate, it cannot be a date that occurs before the OrderDate.  Which constraint would be the best to place on this attribute?

```
A. Primary Key
B. Unique
C. Foreign Key
D. Check
```

If anybody can help it would be great these are the only question that I'm really stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

For the third question you would add a check constraint to ensure the ship date cannot be before the order date.